# colored markers disappeared from intellij scrollbar

Tags: intellij-idea

in Intellij Idea on mac, I wanted to remove the extra lint warning yellow marker lines from the scrollbar (still wanted to keep the red & green markers), but upon applying, ALL lines disappeared, so I reenabled all warnings (in editor->inspections) but still nothing on the scrollbar.

How do I get those warnings back?

PS: I should mention the scrollbar is now transparent such that it overlays the code window. It wasn't before so I think resetting that might fix the problem

Comment: what did you do exactly to remove the stripe marks?

Comment: @lena I went into editor->inspections and unchecked everything.  It also removed the red & green markers so I went back and checked everything, and also did a restore defaults for the profile, but nothing brought back any lines in the scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You can restore to defaults by clicking the cog icon like down below.

[image]

Comment: I did that.  So now I see text is highlighted again to indicate the warnings, but still the scrollbar shows nothing like it did before

Answer (score 0):

It's important to check the **Stripe Mark** Settings in the  **Color Scheme**. **Stripe Mark**s are responsible for the little colored boxes in the vertical scrollbar of the Editor.

[image: Stripe Mark]